# Opengl: Why is my framebuffer not work if my fragment code is in a function?

Tags: c++, opengl, shader, fragment-shader

I have been learning modern OpenGL and in the tutorial I am following I am on framebuffers. There are many examples in the tutorial. So I can call the other buffers later I am putting all the individual buffers in their own functions. My problem though is anything that uses Kernel Effects doesn't work properly when placed in a function.

This is my fragment shader when I place my code in a function:

```
#version 330 core
in vec2 TexCoords;

out vec4 color;

uniform sampler2D screenTexture;

void EdgeDetection();

const float offset = 1.0 / 300;  

void main()
{
    EdgeDetection();
}  

void EdgeDetection()
{
vec2 offsets[9] = vec2[](
        vec2(-offset, offset),  // top-left
        vec2(0.0f,    offset),  // top-center
        vec2(offset,  offset),  // top-right
        vec2(-offset, 0.0f),    // center-left
        vec2(0.0f,    0.0f),    // center-center
        vec2(offset,  0.0f),    // center-right
        vec2(-offset, -offset), // bottom-left
        vec2(0.0f,    -offset), // bottom-center
        vec2(offset,  -offset)  // bottom-right    
    );

    float kernel[9] = float[](
        1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
        1.0, -8.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 1.0, 1.0
    );

    vec3 sample[9];
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        sample[i] = vec3(texture(screenTexture, TexCoords.st + offsets[i]));
    }

    //col = colour
    vec3 col = vec3(0.0);
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        col += sample[i] * kernel[i];

    color = vec4(col, 1.0);
}
```

This is when the frag code is in main:

```
#version 330 core
in vec2 TexCoords;

out vec4 color;

uniform sampler2D screenTexture;

const float offset = 1.0 / 300;  

void main()
{
    vec2 offsets[9] = vec2[](
        vec2(-offset, offset),  // top-left
        vec2(0.0f,    offset),  // top-center
        vec2(offset,  offset),  // top-right
        vec2(-offset, 0.0f),    // center-left
        vec2(0.0f,    0.0f),    // center-center
        vec2(offset,  0.0f),    // center-right
        vec2(-offset, -offset), // bottom-left
        vec2(0.0f,    -offset), // bottom-center
        vec2(offset,  -offset)  // bottom-right    
    );

    float kernel[9] = float[](
        1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
        1.0, -8.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 1.0, 1.0
    );

    vec3 sample[9];
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        sample[i] = vec3(texture(screenTexture, TexCoords.st + offsets[i]));
    }

    //col = colour
    vec3 col = vec3(0.0);
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        col += sample[i] * kernel[i];

    color = vec4(col, 1.0);
}
```

When I put the code in main it works just fine. Any idea why it this is happening? I have included a pic of what happens when I run the program.

[image]

Comment: Modern OpenGL and GLSL are *at least* version 4. You should update that in your `#version` line. Not a solution, just a tip.

Comment: @GraphicsMuncher Depends on your definition of "modern". The core profile was introduced with OpenGL 3.2. If you don't need any OpenGL 4.x level features, specifying version 3.3 is actually not a bad option. It will still give you wider hardware support, and is a subset of OpenGL 4.x.

Comment: Did you check if your shader compile successfully?

Comment: @Jerem There are no errors in my console. If there were It wouldn't show anything on screen.

Comment: float offset = 1.0 / 300 triggers a compilation error on my machine, that's why I'm asking. Did you try moving the function body before the main?

Comment: @Jerem It is before the main in both examples of code I posted. I don't think that is it.